# What is a path added in Additional Include Directories relative to?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

What is a path added in Additional Include Directories relative to? Is it the location of the project (*.vcxproj)? Is it the location of the solution (*.sln)?

Comment: Assuming you mean something like `#include "Somefile.h"` that is including a user defined header file. Also, the location of the solution or project with VS is in the directory in which you defined when creating it and would not need to be included additionally.

Comment: have you read an [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my test, the path is relative to the project directory, which is set to current during the project build. I created the project with two source files: `test.cpp` and `dir1\test2.cpp`. Both include file `test_include.h`, which is placed in the parent directory. Additional include directory is: `..\` Build log:

```
         C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\CL.exe /c /I..\ /ZI /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _DEBUG /D _CONSOLE /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Yu"StdAfx.h" /Fp"Debug\test.pch" /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd /TP /analyze- /errorReport:prompt dir1\test2.cpp test.cpp
         test.cpp
         test2.cpp
```

As you can see, current directory is the project directory, and files in the command line are: `dir1\test2.cpp` and `test.cpp`, both are successfully compiled with the same `/I..\` switch.